# How to shrink user data file in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I have a datafile users.dbf . Its size has incresed to 61GB and is an issue. There is not much data in it , it has different user created in it.
Please help me shrinking the users data file.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: This is a pretty specific question, which might merit more specifics about what version of SQL Server you are running, etc...

Comment: look here: [dba.exchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/can-i-move-rows-between-partitions-by-updating-the-partition-key)

Comment: @Belly S : I am using sql server 2008 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATES to the partitioning column are logically equivalent to a DELETE followed by an INSERT.  So yes, if you update the status column the row will be moved to the correct partition. The impact on performance is the same as a DELETE followed by an INSERT.

However, partitioning is for ease of management (move historical data to slow disks, splitting index rebuilds into smaller chunks, doing large data loads, etc ) not for performance.

If you are doing this for performance, I'd recommend filtered indexes instead of partitioning.
For example, if you have a select like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.c3, t.c5 FROM t WHERE status ='NEW' and datetime > @d1
```

A filtered index is a much better solution than partitioning.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tab_fltr_status_new on t ( datetime ) where (status = 'NEW')
```